# How to align elements in td?

Tags: html, html-table

I have attached image containing elements on my page. I want "format-123-456-7890) exactly below phone element. at present "phone ext" element is wrapped. If i increase size of "format.." element, phone ext element is getting wrapped. don't know solution. here is html code. i want Phone Ext in one line and Format element in one line (don't want to be wrapped).
[image]

```html
<table datatable="0" role="presentation">
  <caption class="hiddenContent">data table</caption>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30%;text-align: right">*First Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="elctnFirstName" id="elctnFirstName" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="40" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right">Middle Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="elctnMiddleName" id="elctnMiddleName" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right">*Last Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="elctnLastName" id="elctnLastName" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right">Email Address:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="256" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right">*Phone:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="elctnPhone" id="elctnPhone" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="12" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right">Phone Ext:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="eltcnPhoneExt" id="eltcnPhoneExt" value="" aria-required="true" maxlength="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 40%;text-align: right">(Format-123-456-7890)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions

1) Use `&nbsp;` in `Phone&nbsp;Ext`

2) Let the table go to its natural width rather than setting the with to 40% and 20%

3) Explicity set the widths of `<input>`. I doubt that the extension field needs to be as long as others

4) Put a nowrap on the cell you don't want to wrap.

5) Use Bootstrap rather than tables to layout your form